# jQuery: Each new click alters CSS differently

Tags: jquery, css, html, video

I just started learning jQuery and have come across an issue I don't know how to solve.

I have an html5 video and want to change its bottom and top margins when I click onto the video, but every new click changes the margins differently.

So the first click changes the margin-left from 120px to 580px, the next click from 580px to 700px, the next click the margin-top from 0px to 100px and then back to the initial setting.

Up to now I have:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('#mask').click(function (){
       $('#mask').css('margin-left',"120px");
         $(this).css('margin-left',"580px");

   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bR9wy/

Any ideas?

Comment: What jquery version are you using? That would help me use your jsfiddle

Comment: why are you using both `$('#mask')` and `$(this)`? They are same. what are you trying to do? Your fiddle doesn't have jquery added.

Comment: if you want to change bottom and top margins, why are changing `margin-left` twice? change `margin-top` & `margin-bottom`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to move a video to a different position based on each click. If that's right then I believe this is what you're looking for. For each click it will increase the data `clicks` by one. you can add to this for click number 4 by use adding `}else if(c === 4){` and so on.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR9wy/5/) I also fixed the HTML in the fiddle and added some css so you could see the box better.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        var c = $(this).data('clicks') || 0;
        console.log(c);
        if (c === 0) {
            $(this).css('margin-left', "580px");
        } else if (c === 1) {
            $(this).css('margin-left', "700px");
        } else if (c === 2) {
            $(this).css('margin-top', "100px");
        } else if (c === 3) {
            $(this).css({
                marginTop: "0px",
                marginLeft: "120px"
            });
            c = -1;
        }
        $(this).data('clicks', ++c);
    });
});
```

Comment: Oooh ok that makes sense, so I need to make the click into a variable I didn't think about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

check the next code.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var click = 0 ;
   $('#mask').click(function (){
       click++;
       switch(click){
           case 1:
            $(this).css({'margin-left':"580px", 
                         'margin-top':"100px"});
           break;
           case 2:
           $(this).css({'margin-left':"700px", 
                        'margin-top':"200px"});
           break;
           case 3:
           $(this).css({'margin-left':"120px", 
                       'margin-top':"0px"});
           default :
               click = 0;                        
           break;
       }

   });
});
```

**DEMO**

[JSFinddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johan_16/FQ6D2/embedded/result/)